# Where is the expiration of JWT (Json Web Token) saved?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I think the JSW certification flow is as follows.

1. (the client) call api with id and password in login page
2. (the server) return token (HEADER . CLAIM . SECRETKEY) to client
3. (the client) save the token in local storage
4. (the client) call api with token
5. (the server) checks the token for validity and expiration and returns a result to client

Authentication method 5: Whether the combination of the decoded HEADER and the decoded CLAIM matches the SECRETKEY.

I have a question.　Where is the expiration saved?

FYR. I used this library. https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken

Comment: Usually, the token itself has an expiration date included. It is one of the "claims".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expiration is saved inside the CLAIM. As written in the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1).

> 4.1.  Registered Claim Names
>
> > 4.1.4.  "exp" (Expiration Time) Claim
> >
> > > The "exp" (expiration time) claim identifies the expiration time on
> > > or after which the JWT MUST NOT be accepted for processing.  The
> > > processing of the "exp" claim requires that the current date/time
> > > MUST be before the expiration date/time listed in the "exp" claim.

Also, take a look at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/introduction/) it is much easier to read than a RFC.